# Disable Gmail delete confirmation

Tags: gmail, notifications

When I delete email from my sent items, or any other view, Gmail asks for my confirmation to delete mail.

Is there any way to I can turn this confirmation off?

Any browser add-on (Greasemonkey script will do)?

Comment: no. This is because the message isn't in the inbox, it's archived.

Comment: Can someone explain why the down vote? Yeah, what I need may be silly for you, that doesn't mean that you have to vote me down

Comment: I would also like to avoid this dialog. Having read it once I understand that I'm deleting the final copy and don't need to be told every time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NO**. There are no such option available in Gmail or in [Gmail Labs](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/labs) .
None of the popular Gmail [Greasemonkey scripts](http://userscripts.org/tags/gmail?sort=installs) claim to do this.
The best you can do is write your own Greasemonkey script for this or suggest a **Gmail Labs** feature request [here](http://groups.google.com/group/gmail-labs-suggest-a-labs-feature/topics). If it's a popular request it might get implemented.